# parsing json from textarea to api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm trying to create some sort of json request / response simulator. It's a nodejs app that communicates with an external api.

I have a textarea where one could enter a snippet of json code such as

```
 someJson = JSON.stringify({
     "z": {
          "test": "....."
     },
     "v": {
          "test2": "......"
     }
 });
```

and submit the form which then posts to the backend which then calls an external api with that data.

How do I convert this text from a textarea into an object I can then run JSON.stringify on? by just running the stringify on text, It adds backslashes and doesn't remove spaces properly. Even if I were to remove the backslashes and spaces, it'd still a string and the external api is very strict.

Update:

Adding a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b5drLnnq/1/

The issue is that there could be valid data that has spaces or whitespace, but it'd get removed in the process of removing whitespace or having backslashes added from the rest of the object.

Comment: So do they enter JSON, or do they enter the Javascript?

Comment: they enter json as text

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular expression to get text between parenthesis i.e. JSON.stringify():

```
var textAreaText = $('#textarea_id').val();
var rgx = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var match = textAreaText.match(rgx);

var someJson = JSON.stringify(match[1]);
```

edit: changes you wanted

```
var textAreaText = $('#txtArea').val();
//changed regex to match braces        
var rgx = /\{([^)]+)\}/;        
  var match = textAreaText.match(rgx);
//match is an array
jsonmatch = match[1];
jsonmatch = jsonmatch.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t| )/gm,"");
//replace lost braces
jsonstr = JSON.stringify('{'+jsonmatch+'}');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sameersemna/ofjpLx57/2/

Comment: I get a null value 

http://jsfiddle.net/b5drLnnq/1/

One thing as well, there might be actual data like a paragraph that would include spaces, but this approach would remove all the spaces from that instead of just the white spaces from the textarea?

Comment: Hi Sameer, your edited version just gives back the json obj with \n and \t's and comes back as a string beginning with ". how do I get this 

{"glossary":{"title":"example glossary","GlossDiv":

vs.

"{\n    \"glossary\": {\n        \"title\": \"example glossary\",\n\t\t\"GlossDiv\":

Comment: no more \n\t's in your second version of the code. now there are just some backslashes that can probably be easily removed. however, that only solves half of the problem I'm having. 

it's removed spaces from good text like the paragraph,

\"Ameta-markuplanguage,usedtocreatemarkuplanguagessuchasDocBook.
vs.
A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.

you can see the difference by comparing the "json.stringify of textarea contents" and "json.stringify of js object" buttons

and yours is enclosed in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Getting the area text with `$(<your selector).val()` would give you the text. Than you can cleanse the text with your own functio and assign it to an object and stringify it.